# Operating On Object Contained In An ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, iteration

I have a class called Book:

```
public class Book {

private String title;
private boolean borrowed;

public Book(String bookTitle) {

    // Store name of book and mark as not borrowed
    title = bookTitle;
    borrowed = false;
}

public void borrowed(){
    // Set borrowed to true
    borrowed = true;
}

public void returned() {
    // Set borrowed to false
    borrowed = false;
}

public boolean isBorrowed() {
    // Return borrowed
    return borrowed;
}

public String getTitle() {
    // return title;
    return title;
}
```

}

And a class called Library:

```
public class Library {                

private String address;
private ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

public Library(String Address) {

    address = Address;
}

private void addBook(Book book) {

    books.add(book);
}

private void borrowBook(String title) {

    boolean bookFound = false;                        
    // Find Book      
}
```

I need to complete the borrowBook method, which will search through the array list to find if the book is in the library or not, and then use the borrowed() method of the book class to mark the book as rented.

So far I have something like this, although I am struggling with how to call the borrowed method or the getTitle method to be able to operate on the specific book object contained in the array list

```
for (int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++) {

    if (books[i].getTitle() = title) {

         books[i].borrowed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your check in `if` statement is wrong i.e. `if (books[i].getTitle() = title)`
should be replaced by,
`if(books.get(i).getTitle().equals(title))`

and do not forget to check the `borrowed` flag before invoking the `borrowed()` function.

So your final code should look like,

```
    for (int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++)
    {
        if (books.get(i).getTitle().equals(title)) 
        {
            if(!books.get(i).isBorrowed())
                books.get(i).borrowed();
            else
            {
                //Inform user book already borrowed
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logical check should be
`books[i].getTitle().equals(title)`
or say
`title.equals(books[i].getTitle())`.

You're not comparing the two strings correctly.
Also consider the case when one or both of them are `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++) {

    if (books.get(i).getTitle().equals(title)) {

         books.get(i).borrowed();
    }
 }
```

Problem with if check (assigning)

```
if (books[i].getTitle() = title)
```

should be replaced by (comparing)

```
 if (books.get(i).getTitle().equals(title))
```

To make it better

```
private void borrowBook(String title) {

 boolean bookFound = false;                        
 // Find Book  
 for(Book book : books)
 {
    if (book.getTitle().equals(title)) 
    {
       bookFound = true;  
       book.borrowed();
       break;
    }
 }
 //...More stuffs you may want to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have so far wont even comile, elements of an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) cannot be accessed using the index oberator `[]`. You need to use the [List#get(index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) of list. also for comparuing Strings you are using the equal operator, this is not correct, it only compairs references wicht are in most cases not equal for the different String instances (unless interned). You need to use [String#equals(otherString)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) or [String#equalsIgnoreCase(otherString)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-) method.

```
for (int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++) {

    if (books.get(i).getTitle().equals(title)) {

         books.get(i).borrowed();
    }
}
```

You could also use the enhanced for-loop

```
for (Book book : books) {
    if (book.getTitle().equals(title)) {
         book.borrowed();
    }
}
```